# How to make automatic formula between 2 datagridview

Tags: c#, mysql, .net

I would like to know is there a way to do this:

- Column1 in datagridview1 name is current total
- And coumn1 in datagridview 2 sold.

Could I make them use a minus in every update like current total is 10 and sold 5 so current total is going to be 5.

I've try it but I got error of

> operator - can not be applied of operand of type 'string' and and
>   'system.datacolumn'

Do you have any answer :)?

```
Datacolumn column = new datacolumn;
Column. Name = "Total";
Database1dataset.tables [0].column [" total "].expression = " total "  -databasedatatset1.tables[1] columns[" sold"];

Datacolumn column = newdatacolumn;Column. Name = "Total";Database1dataset.tables [0].column [" total "].expression = " total "- databasedatatset1.tables[1] columns[" sold"];
Datacolumn column = new datacolumn;
Column. Name = "Total";
Database1dataset.tables [0].column [" total "].expression = " total "- databasedatatset1.tables[1] columns[" sold"];
```

Comment: Have you tried anything ?

Comment: Yes I have tried but fails alot

Comment: This is rather simple. You should show is what you tried and where you think you went wrong.

Comment: Could you discuss with me to get the solution unless talk about 3 month fail ,, I am new registered for this site to ask,, no similar question

Comment: All my error goes like this operator "-" couldn't used I. This case and rtc

Comment: Post the non working code that you have tried to get some help.

Comment: Okay wait because I am on mobile ,, please approve my question to get attention of more people

Comment: There is no approve and I won't upvote this as currently it is a bad question

Comment: Sorry if it bad I am 15 years old and not English ,, so my language is little poor I don't know how to ask perfectly , so please could you vote it

Comment: You may be edit it to change it to be good ,, could you add edit suggest?

Comment: Sorry the code blocks Is inaccurate as it written from mobile :(